# Hidden authentication in some websites

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I find that some websites have sort of authentication even though no user is logged in. Taking [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/) for example, even a non-logged in user can `freeze` a snippet such that other users cannot modify; whereas the user himself could always modify the snippet even though he opens the link in another browser tab.

My current solution is adding a `type` field (ie, `anonym` and `normal`) in the user model. Then, each time there is no normal user logged in, I systematically generate a unique random ID, register and login as an `anonym` user. It works, but the shortcoming is there are lots of `anonym` users in my database.

Does anyone have a better solution? Is there any "standard" way to realize this kind of hidden authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think method you are looking for is called session id. When you save as anonymous user web app creates a session with a session id which is used to identify the user by link. For example on plnkr it'll be something like `https://plnkr.co/edit/session_id?p=catalogue` where `session_id` is some sort of hash.

To freeze the snippet the session id is written into cookies with the flag, saying, for example, that the state is frozen. If you freeze it in Chrome and open in a Chrome's private window or in Firefox on the same computer, you wouldn't be able to unfreeze it. It'll behave the same way as for other users which have no cookies. In fact using session hash for cookies, rather than any user identification is [better for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146298/why-should-i-use-session-id-in-cookie-instead-of-storing-login-and-hashed-pass).

Now this approach in a sense isn't any better, than creating anonymous users - you still have to save session records into the database to be able to open session context by link. In fact, it might happen to be simpler in your case to do exactly what you did if user is assumed to be present in lots of use cases and places in the code.

In many cases, however, separation of session from user makes lots of sense as it simplifies keeping session state after login or registration. Say some web stores would empty your basket after you register, causing quite a bit of frustration, especially if you put several small items into it which you now have to find again and put back. Those don't have sessions or don't use them correctly on registration or login.

Otherwise, as I wrote it's pretty much the same and you have to deal with many anonymous sessions which pollute the database unless you have some sort of wise retention policy, depending on you use case. Say, for example, a web site similar to `plnkr.co` which is used to share code snippets, and post them on sites such as stackoverflow should better keep those sessions while there are users accessing those say at least once a year. So sessions should have access date and policy would be that it's older than 1 year.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... "you still have to save session records into the database to be able to open session context by link" ==> what does "open session context by link" mean? I don't understand why I need to save session records into the database...

Comment: @SoftTimur, if the context is really simple, lightweight and does not contain any sensitive user data, but most importantly if the context is local to the user's browser, strictly speaking you don't have to (see answer James gave). In the example of plnkr, however, the context is not local to the user's browser as user can save session and send a link to someone else and that other person would see the same code (context is in this case). It's too large to be encoded in the URL, so it is saved somewhere on the server, most likely in the database.

Comment: For playgrounds like plunker, is it impossible to just save the code in the database, but not the anonymous user info; and is it impossible that just the anonymous user info is attached to a session with a session id?

Comment: I didn't say they are creating anonymous users, I said that they are saving session records for each of the saved sessions and that those still can pollute the database in the same way as your anonymous users do. And, yes, I think that is exactly what they do - save a session record with all the code and a URL contains a hash of this session's ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar using Local Storage. It allows you to store data on the browser. A user can then open tabs, close browser completely and reopen etc and the data is still there. It would then appear to be saved for them but actually it's just stored on their browser.

This wouldn't allow others to see what they have done though, so not sure if this is quite what you're after.

I wrapped them in functions in case I chose to change them out later, something like this

```
StoreLocalVariable: function (key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
},

GetLocalVariable: function (key) {
        return localStorage.getItem(key);
},
```

Some info including compatibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API